# excel 10 date input & original date retention

Tags: excel, date

I have an inout form which populates todays date automatically through the 'today' function. This is the date on which the form was generated & signed.

This form is then sent to other departments on subsequent days who check, print, process etc the form.  The date changes to the current date on whichever date the form is opened for processing/printing etc.

Is there a way that I can force the date to remain as it was populated & not recalculate itself on subsequent days.  I have tried 'mid' & 'parse' without success.

Anyone know the answer - I dont want to use macros, just formulae.

Comment: A formula will always recalculate.  You'd need vba for this.  Or teach your users to use Ctrl+;

Comment: @TimWilliams You should post this as an answer, I don't see any other way to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need VBA for this I think.  There is a sort-of formula approach, but it requires your users to change some calculation options in Excel...

Your options:  http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/timestamp.html

Comment: Thanks guys - guess I will have to make them type the date in manually cos my users arnt that clever to use formulas & I'm not clever enough to use VB !!  Thanks anyway.